# console.log issue in a local folder

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, console.log

I just wonder what I am doing with console.log is wrong or not.

I have simple two files as below:
index.html
index.js

and when opening the index.html in chrome(c:\temp\index.html), it does not output console.log message in console tab as below.
[image]
So am I missing something?

As you can see, if you run it below code, it shows console.log properly.

```js
function doSomething() {
    console.log("Work!");
}

doSomething();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>Hi</div>
    <script scr='index.js'> </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your `<script>` tag is incorrect as posted; the attribute should be "src" not "scr".

Comment: Thank you! It is Monday morning. my bad.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you have a typo:

```
<script scr='index.js'>
```

should be

```
<script src='index.js'>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function doSomething() {
    console.log("Work!");
}

doSomething();
```

```html
<div>Hi</div>
<script src='index.js'> </script>
```

You have to change scr to src in that way it will works.